# Update DataGridView after end edit

Tags: c#, events, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView`. I would like to update another cell on the same row after editing another (Enter text on one cell, the next cell (Char count) will update).

I know how to update the cell, I just dont know how to add the event listener to the DVG in code.

I have found the event `CellEndEdit`. The problem is that I add the `DataGridView` in code and am not sure how to add an event listener to it to call another function.

Something like this?

```
grid.CellEndEdit += onEndEdit; // calls onEndEdit anytime cells have stopped being edited
```

EDIT:

Someone wanted the function:

```
private void onEndEdit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Your'e code looks good, what's the problem with that?

Comment: Can you post your method `onEndEdit`

Comment: Ahh... it was what i was passing in as an event. Thanks to the poster below for alerting me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Declare event handler:**

```
dgv.CellEndEdit += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(onEndEdit);
```

**Then create event:**

```
void onEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see implementation of `onEndEdit` but it should look like this

```
dgv.CellEndEdit += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(onEndEdit);

void CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```